# Modify the contents of a string inside a struct using a function

Tags: c

I want to modify the contents of a string which is a part of a struct using a function. The problem is that when I print the string outside the function there is no output but if I print it inside the function the output is FOO which is the correct output. I added a comment in the line where I think the problem is.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN 15
#define NAME_LEN 255
#define PIN_LEN 4
#define BAL_LEN 50

typedef struct account
{
    // account  info
    int account_num[ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN];
    int pin[PIN_LEN];
    float bal;

    // name of the account owner
    char* fname;
    char* lname;

    // link to next account
    struct account *next;
}
account;

account* root;
int num_of_accounts;

bool init(void)
{
    // example
    char account_inf[80] = "FOO|BAZ|123123000012300|1234|5000.00";
    const char delimiter[2] = "|";

    // initialize root and set number of accounts to 0
    root = NULL;
    num_of_accounts = 0;

    // get the first token
    char* token = strtok(account_inf, delimiter);

    // create a new user each line
    account* new_user = malloc(sizeof(account));
    if (new_user == NULL)
        return false;

    // initialize new user info
    new_user->lname = NULL;
    new_user->fname = NULL;
    new_user->next = NULL;

    // walk through other tokens
    int info = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        // filter info
        if (info == 0)
        {
            new_user->lname = token; // problem
            info++;
        }
        else if (info == 1)
        {
            new_user->fname = token; // problem
            info++;
        }
        else if (info == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN; i++)
                new_user->account_num[i] = token[i] - '0';
            info++;
        }
        else if (info == 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PIN_LEN; i++)
                new_user->pin[i] = token[i] - '0';
            info++;
        }
        else if (info == 4)
        {
            new_user->bal = atof(token);
            info++;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    root = new_user;
    printf("%s\n", root->lname);
    printf("%s\n", root->fname);
    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d", root->account_num[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < PIN_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d", root->pin[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%f\n\n", root->bal);

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    // load up all accounts. exit if no account is found or made
    if (!init())
        return 1;

    printf("%s\n", root->lname);
    printf("%s\n", root->fname);
    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d", root->account_num[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < PIN_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d", root->pin[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%f\n\n", root->bal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a horrid repeat of the printing code.  You should create a `dump_account()` function that is given a pointer to an account and prints the details, and then use that, twice.  The encoding of `account_num` and `pin` are intriguing too; I'm not good at reading control characters on the screen.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - He's printing the account# and pin with `%d`. Where would the control characters be coming from?

Comment: You should use `strcpy` when copying strings.

Comment: @DaoWen: I missed the `%d`…so no, there wouldn't be control characters — my mistake.  I'm still not convinced about storing the data as control characters; it will be easier to print if they're stored as ASCII-encoded digits.  It's a bit difficult to see when the control-character storage will be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [manpage for `strtok`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtok.html). The function returns pointers *into the original string*. Since you allocate your input string on the stack, it gets deallocated when you return from the `init` function. When you make subsequent calls to `printf` in `main`, you overwrite the old string on the stack. To illustrate this you can add a bunch of padding in front of your input string so it doesn't get overwritten by the `printf` calls:

```
bool init(void)
{
    // adding this padding should make the program print the desired output
    char padding[1024];
    // example
    char account_inf[80] = "FOO|BAZ|123123000012300|1234|5000.00";
    // . . .
```

However, **that's not really a fix** since you're still using memory that's been popped off the stack. Fortunately, all you have to do to really fix it is to heap-allocate your input string:

```
const char INPUT_STR[] = "FOO|BAZ|123123000012300|1234|5000.00";

bool init(void)
{
    // example
    char * account_inf = malloc(sizeof(INPUT_STR));
    strcpy(account_inf, INPUT_STR);
    // . . .
```

Alternatively, you could just put the string in static memory (i.e. take the `const` off `INPUT_STR` and just use that), but if you do that then keep in mind that `strtok` will modify the original string stored in static memory, so you can't use it again  later.

Comment: It's not clear that the man page for `strtok()` will discuss the business of returning a pointer to a local variable.  The analysis that pointers to local variables are being returned is accurate.  The 1 KiB buffer is an interesting tweak; another approach would be to make `account_inf` a static array (which has the merit of being deterministic and supportable).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - You're right about the manpage I linked to not being very clear (although it _was_ there). I read the version on my mac (a BSD manpage), and it's much more explicit. I changed the link to the OpenGroup's manpage, which is much more clear about what the function does. As for making `account_inf` a static array—that's what I suggested in the last paragraph of my answer. However, I still think that making a fresh copy of the constant static string into heap memory is a better solution since `strtok` clobbers its first argument.

Comment: Thank you :D So it's only a scope problem? Thanks a lot! I get it now.

Comment: @ArbynAcosta - Yup, it was just a scope problem. Yet another solution would be to make copies of the individual "tokens" returned by `strtok` using `strcpy`. That would probably be the best solution since you could actually `free` the individual heap-allocated string copies later, whereas in this version you'd have to know that you can call `free` on `account->lname`...